# Istanbul nyc to include test files

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, istanbul, nyc

I'm currently testing my coverage with mocha and nyc and I noticed some of my assert calls weren't being called. How can I include my test files in nyc to make sure all the asserts are covered?

I tried:

```
"nyc": {
  "include": ["**/*.js"]
},
```

to include every file in the project and

```
"nyc": {
  "include": ["test/*.js"]
},
```

to explicitly include the test files, however neither of these included the test files.

How do I include the test files or what is the better way of ensuring all the assert statements are covered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests are excluded in exclude, if you provide an empty exclude it will not exclude the tests

```
"nyc": {
  "exclude": []
}
```